# elasticsearch fuzzy search space sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, whitespace, fuzzy-search

I have elasticsearch query like ;

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "text": {
                            "query": "yayla kent sitesi",
                            "fuzziness": "2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type": {
                            "query": "2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and there is records

```
"text":"yaylakent sitesi"
```

but I can't get results using fuzzy search its return many unrelated documents. Can someone help me to have a query which have one or few space sensitive search in field.

```
"query": "yayla kent sitesi"
```

should not combine to,

```
"query": "yaylakent sitesi"
```

Comment: What is your tokenizer / analyzer on the field text ?

Comment: tokenizer and  analyzer  are standart  for all fields . also  type of field "text" is text